# Solving Equations using logarithm

Tags: logarithms

Here is a system of equations for which I am having difficulty solving:

\begin{cases} a^{2x}.b^{3y}=m^5 \\ a^{3x}.b^{2y}=m^{10} \end{cases}

Comment: There are two single equations or is this a system?

Comment: A system, as far as I know

Comment: The title says "using logarithm" but the equations are still in an exponential form—what happens when you use the logarithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a^{2x}.b^{3y} = m^5$

$a^{3x}.b^{2y} = m^{10}$

Taking natural log on both sides of both equations,

$ln a^{2x} + ln b^{3y} = ln m^5$

$ln a^{3x} + ln b^{2y} = ln m^{10}$

---

$2xln(a) + 3yln(b) = 5ln(m)$ ---{i)

$3xln(a) + 2yln(b) = 10ln(m)$ ---(ii)

---

$x = \frac{2.5ln(m) - 3.10ln(m)}{2ln(a).2ln(b) - 3ln(a).3ln(b)} = \frac{-20ln(m)}{-5ln(a)ln(b)} = 4ln(m - a -b) $

$y = \frac{2.10ln(m) - 3.5ln(m)}{2ln(a).2ln(b) - 3ln(a).3ln(b)} = \frac{5ln(m)}{-5ln(a)ln(b)} = -ln(m -a - b)$

Answer (score 0):

***HINT***

Notice that $$a^{2x}.b^{3y}=m^5 \\a^{3x}.b^{2y}=m^{10}$$

$$\Rightarrow a^{3x}.b^{2y}=(a^{2x}.b^{3y})^2$$

Now solve either of for $a$ or $b$. The solution you obtain will be dependent on $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the logarithms of both these equations will yield a linear system in $x,y$:
$$\begin{cases}2\log(a)x+3\log(b)y=5\log(m)\\3\log(a)x+2\log(b)y=10\log(m)\end{cases}.$$
About solving linear systems, maybe this helps: https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/systems-of-linear-equations-and-inequalities/the-substitution-method-for-solving-linear-systems .